# JQ combine json with key:value

Tags: json, filter, jq

I have two Json files

First :

'''
{
"KeyID": 7532173,
"KeyDetails": "Level 12"
}
'''

Second:
'''
{
"KeyID": 7532173,
"Level": "Access Level"
}
'''

I would like to combine them matching the key:value pair of KeyId

Please advise on how to proceed

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `if ... then ... else ... end`, or more briefly, `select`:

```
jq -s 'select(.[0].KeyID==.[1].KeyID) | add' file1.json file2.json
```